# Google Maps and DART

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dart

I am new to DART. Is it possible to use Google Maps Javascript API on DART? If its not directly possible now, is there any other alternate way?

Comment: 18bytes, the answer to this question has changed. Would you mind moving the green checkmark as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can now use [google_maps package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps) available on [pub](http://pub.dartlang.org). This library allows you to use Google Maps JavaScript API from dart scripts.

Simply add the dependency to your *pubspec.yaml*

```
dependencies:
  google_maps: ">=1.0.1 <2.0.0"
```

Include the Maps API JavaScript using a `<script>` tag.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Then you can use Google Maps from dart scripts. Here's a simple exemple :

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';

void main() {
  final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
    ..zoom = 8
    ..center = new LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    ;
  final map = new GMap(query("#map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the `import` is giving me an error message "Directive out of order". Any clues why it's doing that?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm stuck to use 13851 and I guess that's the problem. I found the right syntax though: `#import('package:js/js.dart', prefix: 'js');`, could help yet somebody.

Comment: Here's what finally worked for me:
https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/ORXJmmmH3fA/WIKyBik1e7sJ

Answer (score 2):

Currently you need to use [postMessage](http://api.dartlang.org/html/Window.html#postMessage) from Dart if you want to communicate with JavaScript (this will eventually change). So for now you'll need to add some JavaScript code to your app that mediates messages to and from Google maps JS API and Dart:

```
function googleMapsCallback(s) { 
   window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(s), '*'); 
}
```

And then in your Dart code:

```
class GoogleMap { 
  GoogleMap() {
     window.on.message.add(received, false); 
  }

  received(MessageEvent e) { 
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data); 
    // do stuff with google maps data 
  } 
}
```

Alternativly you can use [Google Maps REST API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) directly from Dart using XMLHttpREquest

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking only about using Google Maps REST API initially.

Answer (score 1):

Dart now has a JavaScript interoperability library: http://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/

One of the examples on that page is how to interoperate with Google Apps.